# Problem with QTimer() function in PySide6 the function doesn't loop

Tags: python, pyqt, qtimer, pyside6

I have this PySide app and I want to run the function pp every 1 second, but when I run the app it only ran for 1 time.

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PySide6 import QTimer


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        ###
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.pp())
        self.timer.start(1000)
        print(self.timer.isActive())

    def pp(self):
        print("LOL")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    #app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The console outputs:

```
LOL
True
```

I searched in the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QTimer.html#PySide6.QtCore.PySide6.QtCore.QTimer.isSingleShot) but found nothing

Comment: TYPO: change to `self.timer.timeout.connect(self.pp)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your connection is wrong. Change `self.timer.timeout.connect(self.pp())` to `self.timer.timeout.connect(self.pp)`, because you want to connect to the function, not its output.

Comment: Thanks so much, I totally missed that